# Changing the content in another adapter position when a different position is clicked in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Let us assume we have a RecyclerView which has 7 entries.
Is there a way to change the content of the 2nd adapter position when I click on a view in the 5th adapter position?

Answer (score 0):

change in the 5th position of array (you are passing to adapter) inside adapter and notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: I'm clicking on 5th position, but I want the change to happen in 2nd position. ( For example, I want the text in 2nd position to change when I click on something in 5th position )

Comment: You you click on 2nd Position item change value of 2nd poition in your array like
`array.get(5)=your new value`

Answer (score 0):

Keep your conditions(chaning content) in onBindViewHolder And OnClick call notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, it's possible.**

You need to update the valued of the list which you have passed to the adapter. Please update the desire position value in the list and notify dataset to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,first you have to change content 2nd item of array when you click on 5th position then call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() 
so onBindViewHolder will be called

or call notifyItemChanged(1);

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible with use of `notifyDataSetChanged()` after modifying your entries. 
Refer below sample adapter code for this.

```
public class SampleListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SampleListAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private List<String> listData;
    private Context context;

    public SampleListAdapter(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        listData.add(0, "One");
        listData.add(1, "Two");
        listData.add(2, "Three");
        listData.add(3, "Four");
        listData.add(4, "Five");
        listData.add(5, "Six");
        listData.add(6, "Five");

    }

    public void swapList(List<String> listData) {
        this.listData = listData;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView tvDeliveryName;
        View view;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            view = itemView;
            tvDeliveryName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_course_name);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.yout_layout, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String data = listData.get(position);
        holder.tvDeliveryName.setText(data);

        holder.view.setTag(position);
        holder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int pos = (int) view.getTag();
                if(pos == 1){
                    listData.remove(1);
                    listData.add(1, "Your Data");
                    swapList(listData);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }
}
```